# item from arrayList deletes from panel but not from actual arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, jcombobox

Previously I wrote a program that would add users then make a list with checkboxes next to the user's names and then you would be able to select from it and press delete button to delete the user's name along with the checkbox next to it. **Now after building and putting together my actual program I realized that the names actually do not delete from the actual list but only from the panel (therefore it just turns invisible). How can I make it so that it actually deletes from the arraylist and not just the panel? Also is there a way to make it so that it doesn't accept the same user name?**

My complete codes for the program is located here: [GITHUB](https://github.com/76342ck/CHORE-SCORE)

In here when I run the MenuWindow and click on Manage Users my ManageUsersGUI window pops up and it lets me add and delete users. When i close it and press on View Available Chores it opens another window in which it allows me to view chores from a user which i can select from a JComboBox. But it shows all the same repeated names and the names that i deleted. If i go back and press the Manage Users button the window pops up again and has no list of Users from before. It's empty again and if you add the same names it will let you add and again and when you delete it doesn't actually delete.

Here's my code for ManageUsersGUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class ManageUsersGUI extends JFrame {
    public ArrayList<User> users;
    private JLabel title;
    private JLabel addNewUserLabel;
    private JTextField addNewUserTextField;
    private JLabel deleteUsersLabel;
    private JButton addButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JPanel namePanel;
    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500;
    final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;


    public ManageUsersGUI() {
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //construct components
        title = new JLabel ("Manage Users");
        title.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 28));

        addNewUserLabel = new JLabel ("Add new User here:");
        addNewUserTextField = new JTextField (0);
        deleteUsersLabel = new JLabel ("Select which User(s) you would like to delete:");
        addButton = new JButton ("Add");
        deleteButton = new JButton ("Delete");
        namePanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(namePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        //set components properties
        addNewUserTextField.setToolTipText ("Enter name and click on Add button.");
        addButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to Add new user.");
        deleteButton.setToolTipText ("Click here to delete User(s) selected.");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (500, 600));
        setLayout (null);

        //add components
        add (title);
        add (addNewUserLabel);
        add (addNewUserTextField);
        add (deleteUsersLabel);
        add (namePanel);
        add (addButton);
        add (deleteButton);

        //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
        title.setBounds (170, 10, 300, 100);
        addNewUserLabel.setBounds (65, 90, 120, 25);
        addNewUserTextField.setBounds (200, 90, 125, 25);
        deleteUsersLabel.setBounds (135, 120, 281, 25);
        addButton.setBounds (350, 90, 90, 25);
        namePanel.setBounds(225, 270, 140, 0);
        deleteButton.setBounds (200, 300, 100, 25);

        addButton.addActionListener(new AddButtonListener());

        deleteButton.addActionListener(new DeleteButtonListener());

        setVisible(true);
    }      

    private class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = addNewUserTextField.getText();
            ChoreScoreData.getUserList().add(new User(text));

            // Display the changes.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text + " has been added.");

            JCheckBox nameCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            nameCheckBox.setText(addNewUserTextField.getText());
            namePanel.add(nameCheckBox);
            namePanel.setBounds(225, 140, 140, namePanel.getHeight() + 25);
            deleteButton.setBounds(200, deleteButton.getY() + 25, 100, 25);
            JFrame frame = (JFrame) getRootPane().getParent();
            frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() + 25);
            frame.pack(); 
        }
    }

    private class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(Component component : namePanel.getComponents()) {
               if(component instanceof JCheckBox) {
                  if(((JCheckBox)component).isSelected())
                     namePanel.remove(component);
                     for (User user: users) {
                       users.remove(user);
                     }
            }
            namePanel.revalidate();
            namePanel.repaint();
         }   
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("AddUsersPanel1");
        frame.setTitle("Manage Users");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add (new ManageUsersGUI());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE#2:** Added code to remove from arrayList

```
 private class DeleteButtonListener implements ActionListener {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for(Component component : namePanel.getComponents()) {
           if(component instanceof JCheckBox) {
              if(((JCheckBox)component).isSelected())
                 namePanel.remove(component);
                 for (Iterator it = users.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                     it.next();
                     it.remove();
                 }           
           }
        }
        namePanel.revalidate();
        namePanel.repaint();
     }   
}
```

Now gives me this long error:

```
         ----jGRASP exec: java MenuWindow

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ManageUsersGUI$DeleteButtonListener.actionPerformed(ManageUsersGUI.java:96)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: I can't see the code where you actually delete a user from your arraylist. Something like `users.remove(index)`

Comment: What line corresponds to line 95 ? (of your **ManageUsersGUI.java**)

Comment: @Sparta `for (User user: users) {`

Answer (score 3):

Nothing's being removed from the arraylist because you aren't removing anything from an arralist. I can see you're removing components from a swing component but never from the arraylist

**EDIT:** You posted the code for removing from an arraylist, you're removing from the collection you're iterating through, which is always bad news.
You should use an iterator, like so:

```
for (Iterator it = users.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```

**EDIT AGAIN:** Since you seem to be removing everything from your arraylist, why not simply use

```
users.clear();
```

?

Comment: This compiles but when I run the actual whole program in my GitHub which is described in my 3rd paragraph I get the same error. Updated above.

Comment: The code you've posted compiles? It would, but you cannot remove elements in an enhanced for loop from the underlying collection

Comment: Sorry you answered too fast before I could post the update.

Comment: What's this code doing? 
ChoreScoreData.getUserList().add(new User(text));
It looks like you're adding to an arraylist elsewhere in the addButton action method, and in the remove method you're trying to delete items from an arraylist that hasn't been initialised yet, i.e. it is null

Comment: where? Sorry there's so many coding now i'm just confused as to where it is located because the other codes are not written by me but by my group members.

Comment: In your "actionPerformed" method for your add button, you're adding to an arraylist from either an object called "ChoreScoreData", or to a static arraylist in the "ChoreScoreData" class, then in your actionPerformed method for the removeButton, you're removing from users which is the arraylist in your "ManageUsersGUI" class

Comment: I think she did that so that it would save in a txt file so that when people closed the whole program it would then save the list of users and all the chores and when you went back on the program you could edit it again and manage new chores and old chores with new users or the old users from before.

Comment: @pyuntae - I don't think this answers the dbrown93 observation of users are getting added to and arrayList in "ChoreSetData" class and while deleting it is deleting from "users" arrayList which is different. I believe you might have already taken care of this but in case not, make sure you have implemented  equals method in the User class, else arrayList will not be able to find the right User object for deletion

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu what do you mean by the equals method? Like make it so that users equal the ChoreSetData?

Comment: @pyuntae I mean User object need to implement the equals method. Else list won't be able to find/delete the user object later unless you pass same user object reference.Refer to the remove method contract at [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu how do i do this? `public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return 
   }`

Comment: @pyuntae You can either write it manually by comparing the fields you are interested in or if using IDE it will allow you to generate it. For user object it could be `@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
 if (this == obj)
  return true;
 if (obj == null)
  return false;
 if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
  return false;
 User other = (User) obj;
 if (userName == null) {
  if (other.userName != null)
   return false;
 } else if (!userName.equals(other.userName))
  return false;
 return true;
}`. See dbrown93 observation-User is added to list in "ChoreSetData" & delete on different list

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu it still gives me the same NullPointerException

Comment: @pyuntae It is because the users object is never initialized in ManageUsersGUI class. Check DeleteButtonListener class I think you should replace`for (Iterator it = users.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}` with `ChoreScoreData.getUserList().remove(new User(((JCheckBox)component).getText()));` if the intent is to delete the selected users.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu Thank you! I think that worked since it no longer gives me an error. Would you also happen to have any idea on how to make it so that the list of names that weren't deleted stay on the page when accessing the window again? Everytime I close it and try to do something else then go back to the window, all the names are gone.

Comment: In that case you need to manage the users in some persistence store(database, filesystem etc) and populate users from this store whenever opening that window